# How to use Redux store in one component without Provider but with connect, because children aren't necessary?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to use `connect` for its performance optimizations and ease of use with `mapStateToProps`. I don't think I need to pass the store to the component from a `<Provider>` wrapper component to any child components, because I don't have any child components that will need the store; I want the store to be in one component, which is "Header.jsx". Mainly, I don't have any other components, other than the default React, and Material-UI, ones, that I want to use the store with.

How would I go about it? I tried to pass the store through `defaultProps` and used `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)` but it keeps saying `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Header)".` I read that context is what's used to get props passed down the tree using the provider.

I'm new to Redux and React so if I'm going about this completely the wrong way, please let me know.

If using `connect` can't be done without a provider, how would I go about wrapping my class from the inside?

Example:

```
class componentName extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    };
  render() {
      return (
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      );
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(<Provider store={storeName}>componentName</Provider>); // Maybe something like this?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you simply cannot use `connect()` without the `<Provider/>` - it depends on that pattern being followed. If you want to use `connect()`, the connected component must be a descendant of the provider. The example you have suggested of including the `<Provider/>` in the call to `connect()` will not work, as:

a) That method takes a react component class, not an already instantiated react element, and
b) Even then, it creates a component class that, upon being instantiated/mounted, checks the context for a store, and this happens both above (in terms of DOM-hierarchy) the Provider that would create the context and before it is mounted and has a chance to create that context.

What's the reason you are against using the `<Provider/>`? Are you trying to prematurely optimize because you think including the provider at the root of your app will have some performance impact? If so, I think you may find there is no appreciable impact from including it, or if you are experiencing one, I would suggest that the problem may be in the setup of your reducers, not simply in the use of `<Provider/>`.

If you are absolutely set on not using the reducer, you could take your `Store` object (returned from wherever you are calling `createStore()`), and, in the `componentDidMount()` of your one component that needs it you could `store.subscribe()` to listen to state changes, then use `store.getState()` to get those changes and load them into state. But eventually, you'll find you are just reimplementing `<Provider/>`, although maybe without the context part.

TL;DR: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the fact that the provider doesn't have a performance impact, as well as confirming that connect cannot be used without provider. I'm using redux in one component only (Header.jsx), and didn't want to wrap it at the App.jsx, wanting to keep all the redux code, and any code related to the header, localized in Header.jsx. I suppose I'll simply use a HOC to wrap it with Provider in it.

Comment: I'd still question what the benefit is of not wrapping the provider around the entire component, but I guess I don't know your whole situation. Just a note that the Provider-providing HOC will have to wrap the connected HOC, not vice versa, so if you have a `wrapWithReduxProvider()` HOC you will need to use: `wrapWithReduxProvider(connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Header))` as `connect(mapDispatchToProps)(wrapWithReduxProvider(Header))` will never be able to work.

Comment: I totally understand OP's sentiment. With all those contexts and HOCs it's even hard to browse the component tree. Every library wants to put something there, while in reality there should be just one top-level context component for all this stuff.